# Incorrect RowIndex when using Syncfusion SfDataGrid with Column Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, syncfusion

Firstly I have to confirm that Syncfusion KB is so ugly...

I have a Syncfusion Datagrid bounded to a data source, and for some reason, I needed to group it on a specific column (Store Code).
[image]
Without grouping, everything seems to be OK, for example, row ID 17 is at index 1, and row ID 18 is at index 2 (one-based not zero-based).
However, the problem is:

When I use Grouping, like the image above, the row ID 17 is at index 2 (and should be 1), and the row with ID 23 is at index 10 (and should be 6).

What happened is that all group headers (like 'StoreCode: XXXX - x Items') are calculated as rows, and subsequently increased the index by 4.
This produces a big mistake when querying the underlaying data source because the indexes aren't the same.
I found [this link](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/10036/incorrect-rowindex-from-checkbox-in-datagrid-with-groupings) on Syncfusion and tried to apply the steps but with no luck.

Code snippets:

```
 private void DgQueuedOrders_CellButtonClick(object sender, Syncfusion.WinForms.DataGrid.Events.CellButtonClickEventArgs e)
{

int CurrentRow = e.RowIndex;

DataTable gridDataTable = DgQueuedOrders.DataSource as DataTable;

int rowIndx = DgQueuedOrders.TableControl.ResolveToRecordIndex(CurrentRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the provided details, we suspect that your requirement is to get the record corresponding the clicked button in both with and without grouping in SfDataGrid. You can achieve this by using the following code example.

Code example :

```
private void SfDataGrid1_CellButtonClick(object sender, Syncfusion.WinForms.DataGrid.Events.CellButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    int CurrentRow = e.RowIndex;

    DataTable gridDataTable = this.sfDataGrid1.DataSource as DataTable;

    int rowIndex = this.sfDataGrid1.TableControl.ResolveToRecordIndex(CurrentRow);

    if (this.sfDataGrid1.GroupColumnDescriptions.Count > 1)
    {
        var record = sfDataGrid1.View.TopLevelGroup.DisplayElements[rowIndex];
        if (!record.IsRecords)
            return;
        var row = (record as RecordEntry).Data;
    }
    else
    {
        var record = sfDataGrid1.View.Records[rowIndex];
        if (!record.IsRecords)
            return;
        var row = (record as RecordEntry).Data;
    }
}
```

Regards,
Mohanram A.